# Return Max Dates from Multible Table Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

**Client**

```
cid         name
----------- --------------------
1           Abe
2           Bill
3           Charlie
```

**ClientVisit**

```
vid         cid         service
----------- ----------- --------------------
100         1           Eval
101         1           Eval
102         2           Consult
103         3           Eval
```

**VisitApproval**

```
aid         vid         approved_on
----------- ----------- -----------
90          100         12/01/2014
91          101         01/10/2015
92          102         02/12/2015
93          103         NULL
94          104         03/12/2014
```

I need to create an output that returns the MAX date for an Eval and NULL if it does not exist:

```
Results
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
1           Abe                  Eval                 01/10/2015
2           Bill                 NULL                 NULL
3           Charlie              Eval                 NULL
```

Earlier today I ran into a similar issue, with only two tables and was able to resolve the issue using a query similar to below:

```
  SELECT    c.cid ,
            c.name ,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(COALESCE(ce1.period_end, '1999-09-09')), 101) AS Auth_End
  FROM      Clients AS c
            INNER JOIN ClientEpisode ce1 ON c.client_id = ce1.client_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientEpisode ce2 ON c.client_id = ce2.client_id
                                                 AND ce1.episode_id < ce2.episode_id
```

Now I have to do the same thing except I'm doing it across three tables rather than two and my mind is going to explode.  What's worse, I think I'm going to have to do this three times, once for each service.  I'm trying to keep it simple for now, how do I get the max date from a across a many to many join table?

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified your tables and left out something but looking at it logically, Approved_On is an attribute of the visit, so why isn't it a field in the VisitApproval table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    c.cid,
    c.name,
    cv.service,
    max_date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(va.approved_on), 101)
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN ClientVisit cv
    ON c.cid = cv.cid
    AND cv.service = 'Eval'
LEFT JOIN VisitApproval va
    ON va.vid = cv.vid
GROUP BY
    c.cid, c.name, cv.service
```

Comment: I could kiss you!  I'm not sure what I was missing, but that did it.  Now to merge it into my larger query...